# unable to display validation error from a partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, haml

im not able to display the validation error, even though it is validating the form.
In my partial form

- if @post.errors.any?

seems to be the problem, the @post returns a false for error and so no error is displayed.
but the @comment returns a true for error, but im not able to replace @post with @comment since it throws an undefined 'comment' error..

my partial form which is begin called inside the show:

```
%html
%head
%title= @post.title
  %body
    %h2 Create Comments:
    = form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f|
      - if @post.errors.any?                # <--- Unsure what to do here..
        #error_explanation
        %h2
          = pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")
          prohibited this cart from being saved:
        %ul
          - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li= msg
    = f.label :Name
    %br
    = f.text_field :name 
    %br
    %br
    = f.label :Text
    %br
    = f.text_area :text
   %br
   %br
   = f.submit
```

my comments controller:

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
   respond_to do |format| 
if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
else
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
end
   end
 end
```

this is show page from which im rendering the file:

```
%html
%head
  %title= @post.title
%body
  %strong Author name:
  = @post.author_name
  %br
  %br
  %strong Title:
  = @post.title
  %br
  %br
  %strong Email:
  = @post.email
  %br
  %br
  %strong Description:
  = @post.description

  %h2 Comments for this Post:

  = render :partial => @post.comments

  = render :partial => "comments/form"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) on your post model to check for validation errors on your associated model.

Comment: thanx for replying..the validation works fine but im not able to display the error inside the if condition the @post fails the if condition and comes out..

Comment: If you use the validates_associated, @post.errors will return errors for comments, and you can display them easily....

Comment: i did try it but it stil doesnt give me the error message..and when i debug the code i dont have the error message inside the @post..

Answer (score 0):

You have to render new action if `@comment.save` fails

```
if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
else
    render :action => "new" 
end
```